# Suppress corresponding author footnote

Tags: symbols

Looking for some help to suppress the corresponding author footnote in the reference section.

When using the following example:

```
\documentclass[prb,onecolumn,preprintnumbers,amsmath,amssymb,superscriptaddress]{revtex4}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\title{My paper}
\author{ABS}    
\thanks{}    
\affiliation{University}
\end{document}
```

I get an asterisk symbol @ the author name (which is what I need to indicate a corresponding author) 
but it also generates an asterisk in my reference section.

References:

*

(1) J. Doe, Nature 2005, 124.

How can I suppress the footnote to appear in my reference section?

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @jarauh. I have modified the LaTeX code. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Well, if I understand your question right, then you want to add a second author to the paper.

Your given MWE is not complete, you missed for example command `\maketitle` to create the title sequence for the paper.

Command `\thanks` includedes a footnote (with the asterix), so if you do not want it just comment is out (as I did in the following MWE) or just delete it.

Command `\affiliation` adds a numbered footnote into the title section, if you don't want it just comment it (as I did in the following MWE) or delete it.

Corrected MWE:

```
\documentclass[prb,onecolumn,preprintnumbers,amsmath,amssymb,superscriptaddress]{revtex4}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\title{My paper}
\author{Firstname Lastname}
%\thanks{content of thanks}
%\affiliation{University}
\author{Firstname1 Lastname1}

\maketitle
text text text \footnote{footnote text footnote text footnote text footnote text }
text text text 
\end{document}
```

and the result:

[image: result of mwe above]